# Google Cloud Datastore: Exporting entities that match a certain query

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

**Background**

I need to send out a large batch of notifications to around ~1 mil devices and I'm building it out using Google Cloud Functions.

In the current setup I enqueue each device token as a PubSub message that:

- stores a pending notification in DataStore, used for keeping track of retries and success status
- attempts to send the notification
- marks the notification as either successful or failed if it's retried enough and hasn't gone through

This process is manually kicked off by a human uploading a CSV with all the tokens. The in-built retry should be enough in principle but I wanted to make sure that if something is off with either the cloud functions themselves or APNs/FCM that I could return a CSV of all the failed tokens in the same format it was uploaded so that the user can retry only the failed one when/if they think it's a good idea.

I run the notifications as part of a job which I use for querying together with the notification's status. To do this I've set up a compound index on `job_id` and `status` and I run a query over all the notifications that match and want to either stream that as a file to the user or store it in Google Cloud Storage so the user can download it from there.

**Issue**

Assuming something close to the amount of total notifications fail and that I want to get all the tokens in one file, my first implementation was just iterating through all the matching entries and building the result. The issue is that it takes around 1 minute per 100_000 entries when retrieving them this way. For something close to all notifications it would take me beyond the max timeout of a Cloud Function. Each entity is around a total of 300 bytes which makes the whole export around 300MB. I could probably reduce this to about half/two-thirds the size by adding a bigger index that would let me do a projection for just the fields I want.

The only alternative I can think of is sharding the notifications to split up the whole group in let's say 100 shards, create 100 files with 10k notifications each and then download them all and stitch them together when the user tries to download the file.

The reason I'm posting the question is that this feels like a relatively simple problem and this solution feels a bit more complicated than I'd expect so I figure I might be missing something.

**Questions**

- Am I missing an obvious, easier way to achieve what I want?
- Is sharding just the expected way to go for something like this and I should just accept the complexity?

**Code**

Just for clarity this is the snippet of code I'm running and I just iterate over the response that this returns in order to produce the output.

```py
    def get_failures(job_id):
        query = client.query(kind = Notification.kind)
        query.add_filter('job_id', '=', str(job_id))
        query.add_filter('status', '=', "failure")
        return query.fetch()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The robust solution to this problem is using Google Dataflow. I currently use it to do exactly this, producing csv files in Google Cloud Storage that contain all ~500k records that match a given datastore query.

Getting it setup can be a bit involved, though.

Before getting this going I used Google Task Queue which has a 10 minute timeout instead of a 30 second timeout. I'm not sure if you can do this purely within cloud functions, or if you'd need to whip up a simple app engine project to act as the request handler for these tasks

Comment: I'll give Dataflow a look and see where that gets me, looks like a great lead, thanks for pointing that out. Google Task Queue is something I'd considered before but it doesn't work with purely Cloud Functions so I was trying to find a "native" solution. It is the next thing I'll try if Dataflow doesn't get me anywhere

Comment: Had a quick scan of the documentation, is there anyway to programatically kick off a dataflow job? It seems that I can have a streaming version running continuously but that sounds costly given I want this to run very rarely, or I can kick it off from the UI but I don't see anything that would let me trigger from a process.

Comment: I use an app engine flex instance as my dataflow launcher, like this: http://amygdala.github.io/dataflow/app_engine/2017/04/14/gae_dataflow.html
It looks like this person is able to launch them from cloud functions:
https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-kick-off-a-dataflow-pipeline-via-cloud-functions-696927975d4e

Comment: In the end I used BigQuery for this because it was much easier to set up and worked out well for my use case. I accepted this answer because I’d guess that for a more general constant use application it would be more sensible.